# Cordova Camera doesn't work in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am building a Hybrid Android app using HTML5, JavaScript and IDE(eclipse).

In my app, I made two html page. One is index.html and the other one is camera.html.

[index.html]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
     <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index2.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index" style="width:100%; height:100%">
      <div data-role="header">
       <h1 class="title">Hybird App</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="result"></ul>
           JSON List
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
          <a href="insert.html" data-role="button" >Insert Data</a>
          <a href="camera.html" data-role="button" >Camera</a>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[camera.html]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
 <script>
     var pictureSource;  
  var destinationType;  
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
  
  function onDeviceReady() {
      pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
      destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
  }
  function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }
  function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
  }
  function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
      correctOrientation : true,
      destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
  }
  function capturePhotoEdit() {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, 
      allowEdit: true,
      correctOrientation : true,
      destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
  }
  function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
      correctOrientation : true, 
      destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: source });
  }
  function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  }
 </script> 
</head>
 
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="camera" style="width:100%; height:100%">
     <div data-role="header">
      <h1 class="title">Camera</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">  
      <img style="display:none; wdith:100%; height:100%" id="largeImage" src=""/>
  </div>
     <div data-role="footer">         
       <a href="index.html" data-role="button" >Main</a>
         <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
      <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
      <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
      <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
      <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage"  src="" />
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[index.js]

```html
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

[index2.js]

```html
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var url="http://192.168.0.26/android/json.php";
 $.getJSON(url,function(result){
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
   var id=field.id;
   var title=field.title;
   var duration=field.duration;
   var price=field.price;
   $("#result").append("<li><a class='item' href='form.html?id="+id+"&title="+title+"&duration="+duration+"&price="+price+"'>" +
     "<span class='item-note'>$"+price+"</span><h2>"+ title + " </h2><p>"+ duration +"</p></a></li>");
    $("#result").listview("refresh");  
  });  
 });
});
```

[MainActivity.java]

```html
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
 */

package app.su.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

The index2.js which I add operates normally in the main page(index.html) and it moves to the camera.html page through the button and the problem isn't trying to use the Camera function.

All JavaScript Sources are not working in camera.html.

Cordova-Whitelist is a problem that I guess. Or is there the other problem?

The hybrid app development is not used in being the first time. Wish many helps.

+

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKmtu.png)

This image is error log when i touch "Capture Photo" button in my app.

Comment: Check for the camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml is already added.

Comment: @ajantha If camera sources move from camera.html to index.html, Camera function is well worked. Therefore, this problem seems to be not.